# Limit the up down movement of divs with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, divider

I making a "to do list" of task to be done. I have some buttons that will move the tasks up and down on the list.

I go the up and down buttons going. My only issue is that the task divs are able to move up and down the entire page. How can I keep the task divs to only moving up and down on on each other?

Thank you!

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.up_button').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.task').insertBefore($(this).parents('.task').prev());
 });

 $('.down_button').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.task').insertAfter($(this).parents('.task').next());
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="task col-sm-12">
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" name="task1" value="taskID1" /></span> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Write HTML" readonly>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default up_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> Move Up</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default down_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span> Move Down</button>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="task col-sm-12">
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" name="task1" value="taskID1" /></span> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Write XML" readonly>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default up_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> Move Up</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default down_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span> Move Down</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st:** I think you need to define `$(this)` before going to insertAfter or insertBefore

**2nd:** you can use `.closest()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.up_button').click(function(){
        var ThisIt = $(this);
        $(this).closest('.task').insertBefore(ThisIt.closest('.task').prev('.task'));
    });

    $('.down_button').click(function(){
        var ThisIt = $(this);
        ThisIt.closest('.task').insertAfter(ThisIt.closest('.task').next('.task'));
    });

});
```

[**Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/uu5ufkj9/)